# How to prevent the format change of a dataframe when copied into a Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following line of python code which copies the content of a dataframe into a Excel file:

```
unified_dataframe.to_excel('FinancialAnalysis_'+timestr+'_.xlsx', sheet_name='Banks', index=False)
```

The first two columns of my dataframe contains data formatted as text but the remaining columns of the dataframe have data formatted as float but, when they are inserted into the Excel file, they are inserted as text. How can I prevent this or convert the Excel columns of interest from text to float (excluding the headers)?

**Edit**
To answer the question from @BigBen, below some additional information:
Regarding the unified_dataframe.dtypes, I found out one funny thing. I got the following output:

```
Financial KPI                                      object
Year                                               object
BAC (All numbers in thousands)                    float64
C (All numbers in thousands)                      float64
CS (Currency in CHF. All numbers in thousands)    float64
JPM (All numbers in thousands)                    float64
WFC (All numbers in thousands)                    float64
dtype: object
```

However, after the below lines of code which I use, first to calculate the average on one additional column and second to specify the number format of the dataframe before I send them to the Excel file, the dtypes change:

```
unified_dataframe['Average'] = unified_dataframe[company_list_average].mean(axis=1)
for i in list_of_columns
    unified_dataframe.loc[:, i] =unified_dataframe[i].map('{:,.0f}'.format)
```

Below the dtypes:

```
Financial KPI                                     object
    Year                                              object
    BAC (All numbers in thousands)                    object
    C (All numbers in thousands)                      object
    CS (Currency in CHF. All numbers in thousands)    object
    JPM (All numbers in thousands)                    object
    WFC (All numbers in thousands)                    object
    Average                                           object
    dtype: object
```

Below a print of the first lines of the dataframe

```
Financial KPI        Year  ... WFC (All numbers in thousands)     Average
0  Total Revenue         TTM  ...                     74,981,000  91,295,750
1  Total Revenue  12/31/2021  ...                     78,492,000  90,294,250
2  Total Revenue  12/31/2020  ...                     72,340,000  88,209,250
3  Total Revenue  12/31/2019  ...                     85,063,000  91,750,250
4  Total Revenue  12/31/2018  ...                     86,408,000  90,180,000
```

Comment: What does "formatted as float" mean? Please share some sample data (e.g. `unified_dataframe.head()`, as well as the results of `unified_dataframe.dtypes`.

Comment: Hi @BigBen. I update my post above to answer your question

Comment: You have strings, not floats. Instead of `format`ting, use the `float_format` parameter of [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).